# Th Electron Window OnBlur Event [unhandled error]

Tags: javascript, electron

This error occurs seldom in the app when it loads (Not all the time). The **index.js** is the main file ,selected in **package.json**, and the **script.js** is the file connected to main html file of the electron app.

[image]
**index.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let window;

var APP_DIR = '/app/';
var IMG_DIR = '/images/';

function createWindow() {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true },
        width:610,
        height:679,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, APP_DIR, IMG_DIR, 'icon.png'),
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        fullscreenable: false
    });

    window.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, APP_DIR, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

**script.js** (where the error occurs)

```
var {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote;

BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().on('blur', function() {
    windowBlurHandler(); //a function
});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()` returns `null` when all windows are blurred. You are getting the error because listeners cannot be registered on `null`.

Try something like this instead:

```js
const mainWindow = require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow()

mainWindow.on('blur', function() {
  windowBlurHandler()
})
```